# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=10'

Tags: mysql, gerrit

I am posting this to save another dev hours of wasted time. Mysql release candidate 5.6.7-rc is junk. As as dev I usually follow as closely as possible with latest version. This caused me hours of debugging gerrit and mysql. The answer is to use a stable version. I hope this helps someone else.

Not sure on the SO protocol for doing something like this - so just posting as a question.

```
mysql> select VERSION();
+--------------+
| VERSION()    |
+--------------+
| 5.6.7-rc-log |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=10;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=10' at line 1


mysql>  select VERSION();
+------------+
| VERSION()  |
+------------+
| 5.5.28-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Older versions of MySQL employed SET OPTION, but this syntax is
>   deprecated in favor of SET without OPTION.

SET OPTION syntax is deprecated, and was removed in version 5.6.

You should just use `SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=10;` instead.

Look at the ***[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html)***.

> **Incompatible Change:** The obsolete **OPTION** modifier for the **SET**
>   statement has been removed.

Comment: I looked - I could not find that in the docs - this is a 3rd party app (ie gerrit) - can you show me the deprecated link?

Comment: Oh and IMHO deprecated should be accepted at least for 3 for 4 years - not between latest stable and current RC versions ;-)

Comment: Perfect link, thanks for the help. Hopefully this will help someone else :-)

Comment: Did they mark that option as deprecated for any amount of time or is Oracle trying to kill mysql though shoddy updates?

Comment: I use libs that is beyond my control... is there a way to configure MySQL to continue accepting the deprecated command?

Comment: Broken link.  Found a new URL for the same:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html